# MySQL select sum then two grouping

Tags: php, mysql, sum, where-clause, having

I have a table with `id, name, type, price, name, date and type_2`.

Theses are bills. What do I have to query if I want to select all the bills between First May and 6 june that are to `Mr. X`.

My code so far:

```
SELECT sum(prix)
from notes_de_frais
WHERE date between '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-06'
HAVING name='Mr. X'
```

To only select the date and the owner of the bills, but it wont work.

What if I want to put 3 arguments or more (i.e. date, owner, type)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: isntead of `HAVING name='Mr. X'` use: `AND name='Mr. X'`

Comment: or put `name` before the date clause: `WHERE name='Mr. X' AND date between '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-06'`

Comment: it should be  sum(price) not  sum(prix)

Comment: Typo of two `name` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend your WHERE clause to include other criteria using AND. And if you are going to SUM, you should use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT SUM(prix) from notes_de_frais 
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-06'
    AND `name`='Mr. X'
    AND `type`='plane tickets'
GROUP BY `name`;
```